# How can I remove handling from a Magento site?

Tags: php, magento

I would like to remove the "Handling" from the "Shipping & Handling" line of the website, my client charges shipping but never handling.

How can I remove this from the front end of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the `Flat Rate` shipping method in Magento.

To change the name, do the following in the Magento admin:

1. Go to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods`
2. Expand your shipping method. EXAMPLE: `Flat Rate`.
3. Modify the `Title` and `Method Name`
4. Clear your block caches from `System > Cache Management`.

If it's not this, you need to be more clear as to where this text is appearing.  If it's part of a template file, you can use the translation CSV files to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. I wanted to remove the word "Handling" that shows up in "Shipping and Handling" on the site. This can be removed by editing this file: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php

Answer (score 0):

i am going to give another answer in here because, a core change of the files is not ideal and the accepted answer doesnt actually change the line "Shipping & Handling" but rather the shipping method.
to change the line open mypackage/mytheme/locale/mylanguage/template/translate.csv and add the following

```
"Shipping & Handling","Shipping"
```